# Update Cell Value as VBA code is running

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning,

Since upgrading to Excel 2013 I have not been able to see changes in cell values as VBA code is being run.  For instance, when the code is running I want cell "A1" to say "Processing" and at the end of the code I change the value to "Complete".

With previous versions of Excel this has not been an issue.  I could simply turn on `Application.Screenupdating = True`.  Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to effect the cell value now. I have gone as far as to create a seperate sub that just changes the value and then activates the code and even that doesn't work.  Processing time can last anywhere from 10 seconds to 3-5 minutes.  Is there a way to get this working again?

```
    Sub status()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Cell change below isn't visible in worksheet unless I pause the code
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Checklist").Range("F2") = "<<<PROCESSING>>>"
    Open_Network_Folder
'The change below is visible as it's the last step in the code process. 
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Checklist").Range("F2") = "Complete"
    End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place a

```
DoEvents
```

statement immediately after setting the cell value.

Comment: That's perfect!  Thank you.  Once the website lets me, I will mark this as the answer.